Kilmarnock Willow dying?
I'm worried about a Kilmarnock miniature willow planted two years ago. It has fresh new leaves on the top but all the underneath branches look dead. I'm in France, moderate climate and lots of rain this spring, clay soil which I thought would retain enough water for it. Last year was unusually dry but I watered it all summer.
Also, the top branches are not 'weeping'... I thought of hanging light weights of some kind from them, or is that a silly idea?
I can't see where to attach a photo.
Thanks!

Welcome! To share a photo or in an existing post, choose [edit], then the image icon (a little landscape) in the menu. A pop-up should appear and guide you through the process. Note that there’s a size limit, so in case of an error, this is likely the cause.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is all the growth with fresh leaves on upright growth, with no growth on weeping branches? A photo would be very useful...
